# Can you view your AP history

Tags: ingress

Can you view your AP history somewhere on the Ingress site?

Like a list of your actions and how much AP you have got for each action?

Something similar to Stack Exchange reputation history in your profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the scanner itself, you can see your past actions with AP gain in "com all" tab. It's likely to be lost after a short time, especially if you play in an active city.

If you want to track your AP and other statistics over time, you can use "Agent Stats" third party apps. You regulary share your "all time" stats to the app and it draws charts to display your progression.

Comment: Too bad this info gets lost...